# confusion matrix wont show CNN model

Tags: python

confusion matrix wont show on pycharm i need a plot of confusion matrix but i just cant make it appear
process finished with exit code 0 is the last code after
227/227 [==============================] - 8s 36ms/step - loss: 0.6156 - accuracy: 0.7225 - val_loss: 0.6402 - val_accuracy: 0.6154
(im just gonna write something here cause it says i need to add more words disregard this ty   )

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/MRI"

CATEGORIES = ["yes", "no"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

        break
    break
print(img_array)
print(img_array.shape)

IMG_SIZE = 50

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass


create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)



pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=5, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
pred = model.predict(X)
pred = np.round(pred)

conf = confusion_matrix(y, pred)

import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(conf, annot=True)

model.save('64x2-CNN.model')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicted values need to match your targets. Print them out to see if one is a float, and the other integers. If it is, do this after `pred = model.predict(X)`:

```py
pred = np.eye(2)[np.argmax(pred, axis=1)]
```

Or any other code that will turn your predicted values into `0` and `1`.

If your targets (`y`) are lists of strings:

```py
pred = np.array(CATEGORIES)[np.argmax(pred, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Hi good morning ye the error is still here 
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and multilabel-indicator targets

Comment: What does your target array look like? And the predicted values? Print them out.

Comment: sorry how do i print out the predicted value?

Comment: `print(pred)` after the line `pred = model.predict(X)`

Comment: i got alot of numbers 
[0.3434138 ]
 [0.10998085]
 [0.27443525]
 [0.07982081]
 [0.1335752 ]
 [0.12472668]
 [0.16125575]
 [0.17189208]
 [0.03809643]
 [0.1982851 ]
 [0.5775432 ]
 [0.08317405]
 [0.21208277]
 [0.4194699 ]
it just shows something like this

Comment: OK, that helps. This is my last guess: `pred = np.array(CATEGORIES)[np.round(pred).astype(int)]` after the `pred = ...` line.

Comment: hi ahh so i did 
    pred = np.array(CATEGORIES)[np.argmax(a, axis=1)]

and this is the out Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/UwU.py", line 106, in <module>
    pred = np.array(CATEGORIES)[np.argmax(a, axis=1)]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: yea this came out
    
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/UwU.py", line 108, in <module>
    conf = confusion_matrix(y, pred)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 258, in confusion_matrix
    labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\condas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 100, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Mix of label input types (string and number)")
ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)

Comment: One last try: `pred = np.round(pred)`

Comment: so i did this
    pred = model.predict(X)
    pred = np.round(pred)
no error on the output but theres also no confusion matrix plot

Comment: I think that's an issue beyond the issue you requested help for. I'm unfortunately not going to be able to assist your for that one. Good luck.

Comment: aight ty very much for ur time ill just see what i can do